# Is it possible to get Tasker to play the next song in Spotify

Tags: tasker, spotify

In Tasker, there is a Media Control action which allows me to move to the next song however it only seems to work for the default Android player.

Is it there a way to hook Spotify up to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible, but using Tasker's built in Media Control Next will not work.

For the action you need to use Script --> Run Shell, and as the command enter "input keyevent 87" without quotes. This is the Android API:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT

Comment: thanks, this works. although it only seems to work sometimes for me. I think it only works if Spotify is already booted up

Comment: Couldn't you insert an action to open spotify before issuing the command to guarantee that spotify is open?  I suppose if you're actively using some other app then this would be annoying but just an idea not an answer.

Comment: I made it open the app, wait 10 seconds, run the shell command (I had to run as root to work). It's working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

[The link](http://androidtrix.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/tasker-spotify-plug-load-and-play/) says how to get tasker to make spotify play:

> Getting Spotify to play.
>
> - Click the “+” icon at the bottom.
> - Select the “System” category.
> - Select “Sent Intent”
> - Set these fields:
>
>   - Action: com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PLAY
>   - Cat: None
>   - Package: com.spotify.music
>   - Target: Broadcast Reciever

From spotify's `Manifest.xml` I can see that there is also a `com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.NEXT` action so I would guess that if you used that instead of `com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PLAY` then it would play the next track.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, how did you explore that manifest? I need to do the same for Audible :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask me how, but this worked for me:

1. Installed Spotify, iHeart and Poweramp.   Disabled BT control for Poweramp.
2. Disabled Google Play Music.  Google Now still works normally.
3. Using the Action Box extension,  I stop all music by playing a 1 second MP3 of silence in Poweramp.
4. Tasker's Play and Next actions work fine with Spotify or iHeart.   I haven't figured how the phone decides which one to start.   But I don't care :-)
   HTH

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... [WaveControl](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MarksThinkTank.WaveControl) says it can control Spotify and has Tasker integration. I'm not a Spotify user, though, and it's much too late to check it out right now.

Answer (score -1):

Mybe this can help you :

http://androidtrix.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/tasker-spotify-plug-load-and-play/

Greetings

Comment: An answer with no useful information except a link to somewhere else is not a good answer. It's hardly an answer at all.